# Command Key (⌘) no longer works while SSHed into Google Cloud (GCP) and Google Compute Enginge (GCE)

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Prior to reverting my computer back to factory specs I was able to use the command (⌘) key to copy and paste things from my clip board into the sshed shell when connected to GCP . Now, I am no longer able to use ⌘ things to copy and paste between the terminal and the rest of my laptop.

I have only seen this issue with GCE (Google Compute Engine) and can use the ⌘ command in terminal but not while I am sshed into GCP.

For reference I use the following GCP command to connect:

```
gcloud beta compute --project "project-name" ssh --zone "zone-name" "instance-name"
```

I am not sure if this is specific to google cloud or ssh in general but any tips / feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this has anything to do with GCP, but more with the Key Configuration on Mac OS itself. Have you tried to contact [Mac Support](https://support.apple.com/en-eg)?

From the GCP documentation all I found was: "[Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/shortcuts)". Where they have a note stating that:

"Note: Some shortcuts might not work for all languages or keyboard formats, and available shortcuts might differ depending on which console page you are on."

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the bother, all I had to do was check off "Secure Keyboard Entry" by clicking on the tool bar and everything works as expected now.[image]